# White square icon in tool bar

Tags: android, push-notification

I read in almost every question that I have to make the app icon transparent, and I did that. However, It still shows up as a white square, but when I pull the notification menu down i see the notification in colors.

At this point, I made separate icons that I designed differently and added them under drawable folders. How do I add them to be used by the push notifications when received?

Extremely confused about this topic. Note: I am using React-Native to build this android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it is supposed to behave after Lollipop I believe.

In the status bar the icon is just a white tinted version of your icon. When you pull the notification bar, it shows normally.

You need to use a notification icon with just the logo, with no solid background.

Check What's App's icon for example to see what I mean.
[image]
[image]